# Whats the proper way to install Jhbuild?

Tags: 14.04, gtk3, pygtk, jhbuild

Im running ubuntu 14.04, and im having difficulty in installing `Jhbuild`. I followed various links when i faced errors, and they are always the same.

The links are:

- http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html
- https://wiki.gnome.org/HowDoI/Jhbuild
- https://developer.gnome.org/jhbuild/unstable/getting-started.html.en

**step 1 : `jhbuild sanitycheck`**

After installation, running `jhbuild sanitycheck` throwed errors like something is missing and also some directory issues like `no directories` or `writable issues`. So i either used `synaptic package manager` or `sudo apt-get install` command to install them and made folder writable if prompted. After doing these steps running `jhbuild sanitycheck` ran succesfully without any errors.

**step 2 : `jhbuild build`**
when i run `jhbuild build` i get

```
W: Circular dependencies detected: meta-gnome-core -> meta-gnome-core-shell -> dconf -> glib -> gvfs -> glib
W: Circular dependencies detected: meta-gnome-core -> meta-gnome-core-shell -> dconf -> glib -> glib-networking -> glib
W: Circular dependencies detected: meta-gnome-core -> meta-gnome-core-shell -> dconf -> glib -> dconf
W: Circular dependencies detected: meta-gnome-core -> meta-gnome-core-shell -> evolution-data-server -> gtk+ -> adwaita-icon-theme -> gtk+
W: gnome-control-center has a dependency on unknown "network-manager-applet" module
W: gnome-control-center has a dependency on unknown "network-manager-applet" module
W: mutter has a dependency on unknown "libXi" module
W: mutter has a dependency on unknown "xwayland" module
W: grilo-plugins has a dependency on unknown "libdmapsharing" module
W: meta-gnome-apps-tested has a dependency on unknown "aisleriot" module
W: gnome-initial-setup has a dependency on unknown "network-manager-applet" module
W: gnome-software has a dependency on unknown "fwupd" module
W: rygel has a dependency on unknown "valadoc" module
Required packages:
  System installed packages which are too old:
    (none)
  No matching system package installed:
    cups (required=1.4)
    cyrus-sasl 
    libtiff 
    ppp 
    file 
    libacl 
    krb5 
    xmlto 
    wireless-tools (required=25)
    gpgme (required=1.0.0)
    mpfr 
    espeak (required=1.46.02)
jhbuild build: Required system dependencies not installed. Install using the command 'jhbuild sysdeps --install' or to ignore system dependencies use command-line option --nodeps
```

Then, if i run `jhbuild sysdeps --install`

```
W: Circular dependencies detected: meta-gnome-core -> meta-gnome-core-shell -> dconf -> glib -> gvfs -> glib
W: Circular dependencies detected: meta-gnome-core -> meta-gnome-core-shell -> dconf -> glib -> glib-networking -> glib
W: Circular dependencies detected: meta-gnome-core -> meta-gnome-core-shell -> dconf -> glib -> dconf
W: Circular dependencies detected: meta-gnome-core -> meta-gnome-core-shell -> evolution-data-server -> gtk+ -> adwaita-icon-theme -> gtk+
W: gnome-control-center has a dependency on unknown "network-manager-applet" module
W: gnome-control-center has a dependency on unknown "network-manager-applet" module
W: mutter has a dependency on unknown "libXi" module
W: mutter has a dependency on unknown "xwayland" module
W: grilo-plugins has a dependency on unknown "libdmapsharing" module
W: meta-gnome-apps-tested has a dependency on unknown "aisleriot" module
W: gnome-initial-setup has a dependency on unknown "network-manager-applet" module
W: gnome-software has a dependency on unknown "fwupd" module
W: rygel has a dependency on unknown "valadoc" module
System installed packages which are new enough:
    python2-devel (required=2.5)
    libv4l 
    doxygen (required=1.8.1)
    gmime (required=2.6.6)
    libvirt (required=1.0.6)
    ragel 
    libXdamage 
    enchant (required=1.6.0)
    dotconf (required=1.3)
    libvpx 
    cairomm (required=1.8.4)
    libxkbfile 
    exempi (required=2.2.0)
    spamassassin 
    libxklavier (required=5.0)
    ruby 
    opus (required=1.0)
    libxml2 (required=2.7.8)
    sbc (required=1.1)
    xcb-dri2 (required=1.8.1)
    libxml2-python 
    shared-mime-info (required=1.0)
    libXext 
    libxslt (required=1.1.26)
    flac (required=1.1.4)
    python-devel (required=3.2)
    libyaml 
    flex (required=2.0)
    xorg-xproto 
    libwebp 
    freetype2 (required=2.4.9)
    speex (required=1.2rc1)
    gbm 
    sqlite3 (required=3.7.3)
    nss (required=3.12.11)
    startup-notification (required=0.12)
    zlib 
    nspr (required=4.9.2)
    taglib (required=1.5)
    dvdread (required=4.2.0)
    mtdev (required=1.1.1)
    texinfo 
    gettext-bin 
    openssl 
    wayland-egl (required=1.0)
    p11-kit (required=0.19.0)
    gl 
    libXcursor 
    xcb (required=1.10)
    pixman (required=0.30)
    gnutls (required=3.1)
    wavpack (required=4.2)
    gnupg (required=1.4)
    polkit-agent (required=0.102)
    xcb-xkb (required=1.10)
    gperf 
    polkit-gobject (required=0.103)
    xkeyboard-config 
    alsa (required=1.0.19)
    poppler (required=0.24.0)
    gudev (required=173)
    highlight 
    intltool (required=0.50)
    py3cairo (required=1.10.0)
    iptables 
    libcanberra (required=0.30)
    json (required=0.11)
    anthy (required=9100h)
    js24 (required=24.2)
    libcap 
    libdb 
    libatasmart (required=0.17)
    libdrm (required=2.4.45)
    egl (required=10.1.3)
    libexif (required=0.6.19)
    xorg-wacom 
    libcanberra-gtk3 
    libffi (required=3.0.0)
    libXinerama 
    libhangul (required=0.1.0)
    libgcrypt (required=1.5.0)
    exiv2 (required=0)
    WebKit1 (required=2.0.0)
    libgphoto2 (required=2.4.13)
    xmlcatalog 
    libicu (required=4)
    libproxy 
    xmllint 
    libjpeg 
    libnl (required=3.2.7)
    xsltproc 
    libnl-genl (required=3.2.7)
    libXrandr (required=1.3)
    libXcomposite 
    libnl-route (required=3.2.7)
    automake 
    liboauth (required=0.9.4)
    cmake 
    libpinyin 
    libXft (required=2.0.0)
    libpng 
    libmusicbrainz (required=5.0)
    avahi (required=0.6.31)
    make 
    bison (required=2.4)
    bogofilter 
    libXt 
    libsndfile (required=1.0.21)
    libXfixes 
    libXtst (required=1)
    c++ 
    libsystemd (required=210)
    wget 
    xorg-macros 
    libsystemd-daemon (required=210)
    libtool 
    cc 
    libsystemd-journal (required=201)
    libarchive (required=3.0.0)
    libsystemd-login (required=210)
    xorg-kbproto 
    libtasn1 (required=2.7)
    sm 
    dbus (required=1.4.10)
    libtool-ltdl 
    glu 
    dbus-glib (required=0.98)
    libudev (required=143)
    libX11 
    libusb1 
    docbook-xsl 
    libuuid 
    smbclient 
Required packages:
  System installed packages which are too old:
    (none)
  No matching system package installed:
    espeak (required=1.46.02)
    mpfr 
    wireless-tools (required=25)
    cups (required=1.4)
    gpgme (required=1.0.0)
    ppp 
    libacl 
    krb5 
    file 
    xmlto 
    cyrus-sasl 
    libtiff 
Optional packages: (JHBuild will build the missing packages)
  System installed packages which are too old:
    (none)
  No matching system package installed:
I: Installing dependencies on system: espeak mpfr wireless-tools cups gpgme ppp libacl krb5 file xmlto cyrus-sasl libtiff
I: Using apt-file to search for providers; this may be slow.  Please wait.
I: No native package found for espeak (/usr/include/espeak/speak_lib.h)
I: No native package found for mpfr (/usr/include/mpfr.h)
I: No native package found for wireless-tools (/usr/include/wireless.h)
I: No native package found for cups (/usr/bin/cups-config)
I: No native package found for gpgme (/usr/bin/gpgme-config)
I: No native package found for ppp (/usr/include/pppd/pppd.h)
I: No native package found for libacl (/usr/include/sys/acl.h)
I: No native package found for krb5 (/usr/bin/krb5-config)
I: No native package found for file (/usr/include/magic.h)
I: No native package found for xmlto (/usr/bin/xmlto)
I: No native package found for cyrus-sasl (/usr/include/sasl/sasl.h)
I: No native package found for libtiff (/usr/include/tiff.h)
I: Nothing to install
```

Tried searching for the errors on `google`, nothing helped.
Got stuck at this point and tried complete reinstallation by removing them completely again and again.. need some help please..

Comment: I did installed `espeak` using `sudo apt-get install`, i get as `espeak is already the newest version`  .  And for `mpfr` it says `E: Unable to locate package mpfr`

Comment: Try installing `build-essential` (`sudo apt-get install build-essential`).

Comment: it says `build-essential is already the newest`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way that I use personally is `apt-file`

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
apt-file update
```

Now you can search the packages for the missing files, eg:

```
% apt-file search /usr/include/sasl/sasl.h
libsasl2-dev: /usr/include/sasl/sasl.h
```

therefore:

```
sudo apt-get install libsasl2-dev
```

Or another example

```
% apt-file search /usr/bin/cups-config
libcups2-dev: /usr/bin/cups-config
```

therefore

```
sudo apt-get install libcups2-dev
```

Comment: Looking at the error logs, it seems that the build process is already using `apt-file`: `I: Using apt-file to search for providers; this may be slow.  Please wait.` But +1 for the pure command-line way ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked . But it worked only by removing the `%` from the `% apt-file search comand`.  And as @SylvainPineau mentioned thanks for pure comand-line way.

Comment: @arvindh The `%` is from my shell prompt and only in my examples to difference between command and output of the command.

Answer (score 2):

The last section of your log is the one that will help you to find the packages to install as debian packages are not (always) exactly named as stated in the error logs.

So you have to install:

```
I: No native package found for espeak (/usr/include/espeak/speak_lib.h)
I: No native package found for mpfr (/usr/include/mpfr.h)
I: No native package found for wireless-tools (/usr/include/wireless.h)
I: No native package found for cups (/usr/bin/cups-config)
I: No native package found for gpgme (/usr/bin/gpgme-config)
I: No native package found for ppp (/usr/include/pppd/pppd.h)
I: No native package found for libacl (/usr/include/sys/acl.h)
I: No native package found for krb5 (/usr/bin/krb5-config)
I: No native package found for file (/usr/include/magic.h)
I: No native package found for xmlto (/usr/bin/xmlto)
I: No native package found for cyrus-sasl (/usr/include/sasl/sasl.h)
I: No native package found for libtiff (/usr/include/tiff.h)
```

For example to find which package to install to get `mpfr` and `/usr/include/mpfr.h`, use the [package contents search engine](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=mpfr.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any) on packages.ubuntu.com

You'll immediately know which package to install, here `sudo apt-get install libmpfr-dev`:

[image]

In order to `jhbuild build`, most of the packages you'll have to install are packages ending with `-dev`, containing the missing header files. So it will be `libespeak-dev` instead of just `espeak`.

Comment: thanks for the information on mentioning about ending with `-dev`

Answer (score 2):

To automate things ..

Do a `jhbuild sanitycheck`, then

```
$ sudo apt-get install apt-file
$ sudo apt-file update
$ jhbuild sysdeps --install <module-name>
```

If no native package found..

```
apt-file update
apt-file search path/to/missing.file
```