# Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS Xenial - Unable to Install gtk+-3, "wayland-egl" not found

Tags: python, gtk3, pygtk, wayland, jhbuild

So I am trying to setup `PyGObject, gtk+-3` on my system to make GUI applications.
I have successfully setup JHBuild required to install these packages as mentioned here:

https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#id2

`PyGObject` is successfully installed on my system.

However, while trying to setup gtk+-3, I have hit a roadblock and the setup always fails with below error:

> No package 'wayland-egl' found

[Error screen-shot attached here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89HrZ.png)

I have tried below but to no avail:

[Whats the proper way to install Jhbuild?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/646734/whats-the-proper-way-to-install-jhbuild)

Is this a known bug with Xenial or am I missing something here? How do I setup `wayland-egl` to resolve gtk+-3's dependency?

Really stuck here, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you build the GTK stack yourself? It is installed by default. Just run Python outside of your jhbuild shell and import GTK3 with `from gi.repository import Gtk` and it should work.

Comment: @Timo : Uh oh! Well, I was following the GTK+3 manual by heart. They mentioned JhBuild as mandatory. Also, when I ran the python script with their "Hello World" example, it failed so one thing led to another and here I am. Anyway, thank you for pointing this out. My actual issue is resolved. However , still I think I should have been able to setup GTK3 on my system.