# How to build gnome-shell on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, jhbuild

I've tried to use the jhbuild system and it refuses to install any of the dependencies erroring out with `I: Nothing available to install`.
Is there any guide or wiki page or blog post that explains how to build the gnome-shell on Ubuntu 18.04?

If there's any ambiguity, I need to build the gnome-shell itself not a shell extension.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
```

**Explanation:**

Even if your problem seems similar to this one:

[Whats the proper way to install Jhbuild?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/646734/whats-the-proper-way-to-install-jhbuild)

your error is  `Nothing available to install` while his error was `Nothing to install`.

The error can be found here in the sourcecode of jhbuild:

https://github.com/GNOME/jhbuild/blob/8c6f2c115efdcd075570a03d64cb861b7d1aca33/jhbuild/utils/systeminstall.py#L314

The requirement is given here:

https://developer.gnome.org/jhbuild/stable/command-reference.html.en#command-reference-sysdeps

> For distributions using APT such as Debian and Ubuntu, this option *[--install]* requires apt-file to be installed.

Comment: I'll try this the next time I want to do something with jhbuild or gnome-shell. I gave up after I was unable to get it working.